# how to GET/load url invisbly in Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript

how can I load url or send GET to a url via actionscript ? I want to create an invisble flash app that can help with analytics.

I am a inexpperienced with actionscript and flash. what good guides are there to gett staarted ? as2 or 3 ? diffiernce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN AS3, this is generally how you'd do it:

```
var req:URLRequest("http://your_request");
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader ();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
loader.load(req);

private function onLoadComplete(ev:Event):void
{
   var result:String = ev.target.data;
}
```

Look up AS3 URLLoader on google to get tons of more info on how to use this.

Comment: how can I blank or edit the referral ? So my analytics @ http://your_request will see that its coming from a blank or different section of my page.